# Checking one field against another using jQuery

Tags: php, html, sql

I have come about quite a problem while programming an order submitting page, the aim of the page is to submit a dispute for an order - providing two fields are filled in, but only if one field is less than another one.

Basically, one is a drop down and the other is a disputes box, the queries are as follows:

If DisputesTextBox = "" and a drop down box = "Please Select..."

Everything is fine - submit button enabled

If DisputesTextBox != "" and dropdown box = "Please select..."

Error ( and vice versa, so if disputes is populated but dropwn = please select...) - submit button disabled

If DisputesTextox != "" and dropdown box = "Other"

Everything is fine - submit button enabled

If DisputesTextBox > shippedbox

Error - submit button disabled

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Item ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Dispute Quantity</th><th>Shipped Quantity</th><th>Ordered Quantity</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `artran09` WHERE `invno` = '$invoiceno'") or die(mysql_error());
                        echo "<center>";
                        $i = -1;        
                        echo "<form action=\"submitdispute.php?invno=".$invoiceno."&ordate=".$placed."\" method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"return confirm('Are you sure you are ready to dispute your order?');\">";

                            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {              
                                $i += 1;                                    
                                echo "<tr>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['item']."</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>".$info['descrip']."</td>";       

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" input name=".$i." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\"  maxLength=\"3\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyshp']." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=".$info['qtyord']." onKeyPress=\"return numbersonly(this, event)\" maxLength=\"3\" disabled=\"disabled\"></td>"; 

                                echo "<td><select name = \"reason$i\">";
                                echo "<option>Please Select...</option>";
                                echo "<option>Short/Not received</option>";
                                echo "<option>Damaged Goods</option>";
                                echo "<option>Product Not Ordered</option>";                    
                                echo "</select></td>";

                                echo "</tr>"; 
                            }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Dispute" name ="Submit">
    </form>
```

Thanks, hope anyone can help!

Edited for Wolf/anyone who can help - what's up with this code here:

-- code i edited --

```
function validateSubmit(){


   // this will loop through each row in table
   // Make sure to include jquery.js
   $('tr').each( function() {
      // Find first input
      var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);
      var qty1 = input1.val();
      // Find Second input
      var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);
      var qty2 = input2.val();
      // Find third input
      var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);
      var qty3 = input3.val();
      // Find select box
      var selectBx = $(this).find('select');
      var selectVal = selectBx.val();
      // Add your validation code here for the inputs and select
      // Return true if all validations are correct
      // Else return false
        if(qty1 = "" && selectVal = "Please Select...") {
            return true;
            alert("You have an error somewhere, please check over your quantites.");
            break;
        }
        if (qty1 > qty2) {
            return false;
            alert("You have an error somewhere, please check over your quantites.");
            break;
        }
   });


}
```

Comment: I do not see any javascript/jquery code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks, i haven't tried any jquery so far, I was just hopefully looking for a solution ? Or some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line

```
onsubmit=\"return confirm('Are you sure you are ready to dispute your order?');\"
```

to

```
onsubmit=\"return validateSubmit();\"
```

Then write the function

```
function validateSubmit(){

   // this will loop through each row in table
   // Make sure to include jquery.js
   $('tr').each( function() {
      // Find first input
      var input1 = $(this).find('input').eq(0);

      // Find Second input
      var input2 = $(this).find('input').eq(1);

      // Find third input
      var input3 = $(this).find('input').eq(2);

      // Find select box
      var selectBx = $(this).find('select');

      // Add your validation code here for the inputs and select
      // Return true if all validations are correct
      // Else return false

   });
}
```

Note that your submit button will be enabled all the time. But submit will work only if your validations are success.

Comment: I don't think that would work - all of the text boxes that need validating are in a loop (referenced using a unique variable for each one, thanks though!

Comment: Inside the validateSubmit function, you can loop through all the text boxes and validate...

Comment: How do you mean? As in, start a for loop?

Comment: For DOM parsing, you can use jQuery. It is to simple.

Comment: Thanks very much, although upon playing around with it i can't seem to get it to work - Check my main post